# Is the angular frequency in damped oscillations constant?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

I've seen thousands of graphs of $A$ (amplitude) changing per cycle, which for me intuitively made me think that $\omega$ will change as well. However, that thought clashes when I think that $$\omega^2=\omega_0^2-\gamma^2$$ being $\omega$ and $\gamma$ the angular frequency without the damping and the damping coefficient, respectively, since that equation does not depend on time.

Comment: [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Damped_harmonic_oscillator).

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks and sorry for the short question, do you recommend me to delete it since some people may think it to be "unuseful" for an OP user?

Comment: Matter of personal judgement…